# how to add new col at the end of csv/txt file python

Tags: python, csv, append, multiple-columns

I am looking for a script to add a new data column into existing csv file by python. I have a file (e.g. file.csv) which will have many rows and few columns. From `for loop` calculation, I got a new array (A in my code here). I want to append that new array (A) as the last column of existing csv file. I used the below code.

```
for xxx in xxxx:
  A= xxx

  f=open("file.csv")
  data=[item for item in csv.reader(f)]
  f.close()
  new_column=[A]

  new_data=[]

  for i, item in enumerate (data):

    try:
        item.append (new_column[i])
    except  IndexError, e:
        item.append(A)
    new_data.append(item)

    f=open('outfilefinal1.csv','w')

    csv.writer(f).writerows(new_data)
    f.close()
```

It did append a new column as the last column. But the problem is the whole column got one same value (A value form the last loop). So, how can I do if I want the A value from each for loop as my last column. Thanks.

Example input file

```
1  2
2  4 
0  9 
4  8
```

A value from each loop

```
3
4
0
9
```

So the final file should show

```
 1  2  3
 2  4  4
 0  9  0
 4  8  9
```

but in my case it shows as

```
 1  2  9
 2  4  9
 0  9  9
 4  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you are overwriting your file inside a nested for loop.

Is A really an array that does not depend on file.csv? Then you could do something like this:

```
import csv

A = compute_new_values_list()

with open('file.csv') as fpi, open('out.csv', 'w') as fpo:
    reader = csv.reader(fpi)
    writer = csv.writer(fpo)

    #optionaly handle csv header
    headers = next(reader)
    headers.append('new_column')
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        row.append(A[index])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**EDIT:**

If you need a row of file.csv to compute your new value, you can use the same code, just compute your new value inside for loop:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as fpi, open('out.csv', 'w') as fpo:
    reader = csv.reader(fpi)
    writer = csv.writer(fpo)

    #optionaly handle csv header
    headers = next(reader)
    headers.append('new_column')
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for row in reader:
        new_value = compute_from_row(row)
        row.append(new_value)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: actually A values are calculated after reading data from file.csv. In that case, how shall I do? Tks